# How can I relate a FK back to the purchasable ID?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

First off, *HUGE* thank you to Lindsey for opening this door for me. Opened up a whole new layer!

I have (another) plugin that is listening to the `commerce_orders.onOrderComplete` event. My plugin inspects the order, and if a specific product was purchased, I capture that and save the pre-defined values in a custom table.

For example, if you buy "Product A", you get to pick two "Product B" options (these options are defined in commerce/CP).

I am able to create the custom table and save the correct values - so far so good.

However, I would like to relate not only the user back to the user account, but the "Product A" back to the purchasable.

Something like this:

**MyPluginRecord.php**

```
public function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'id' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'default' => null),
        'packageId' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'default' => null),
        ...
    );
}


public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'element' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'ElementRecord', 'id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
        'package' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, '????', 'id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
    );
}
```

I'm not sure how to get back to the commerce purchasable record?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: If you take the Record out of the equation, you're looking for an `elementId` column in your table with a FK back to the `id` column in the  `craft_elements` table and a `packageId` column with a FK back to the `id` column in the `craft_commerce_purchasables` table?

Comment: Yes. the `package` variable is the `packageId` that I would like to relate back to the `craft_commerce_purchasables` table (of the corresponding product).

Comment: Boom! Thanks Brad. That was just enough to help take a step back.

Comment: Hah, sorry.  Was going to answer, but you know... life.  Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Brad for breaking it down like that. It helped me take a step back and see what it was I was doing.

Here is the relationship I have that is working:

```
public function defineAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'id' => AttributeType::Number,
        'packageId' => AttributeType::Number,
        ...
    );
}


public function defineRelations()
{
    return array(
        'element' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'ElementRecord', 'id', 'required' => true, 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
        'package' => array(static::BELONGS_TO, 'Commerce_PurchasableRecord', 'onDelete' => static::CASCADE),
    );
}
```

Now I am able to have a relation to the user id `element` and back to my product `package`.